# Schengen type D visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I have got my working holiday visa. Before I enter the Schengen area, can I cancel it? If I cancel it, will it become a problem? (i know it would be recorded).

So, if I cancel it, can I still use my 3-month free visa to entry Schengen countries? Also, is it a bad idea to let it expire ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you can cancel it, but why would you want to?

Comment: I was plan to spend one year in Hungary! So I apply working holiday visa. But I have a job offer back home. But I still need to go Europe (schengen area) for 2 months. That’s why I have these questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Gordon What’s your citizenship? Will your 2 month trip be as a visitor or to work? The consulate of the country that issued your visa should be able to cancel it (they may well ask you for a reason), make sure they put a "cancelled without prejudice" stamp and you shouldn't have problems getting Schengen visas in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Traveller my citizenship is Taiwan which mean I have 3 months free traveling visa. I’m planning go to visit my friend and attending a wedding in Europe (both are in Schengen countries) !

Comment: Btw i find out my visa is Schwngen type D visa.